# Javascript HTML - how to consume web api

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-app

I am basically trying to build a Chrome app (using HTML and JavaScript), in which I want to:

1. Call an API, for instance let's take Google Maps web API (below).

**Google Maps JSON Api**: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Vancouver

2. Fetch a particular value: lets say **long_name" : "Vancouver"** (highlighted in below screenshot)

[image]

3. Store it's value "Vancouver" in a variable and use it later.

In chrome apps, I know I can use HTML and JavaScript/jQuery (correct me if I am wrong about jQuery). I am not sure how to use JavaScript/jQuery and call above API and consume a particular value.

Comment: I recommend you first learn how to use JavaScript / jQuery and then try to implement your solution. If you run into problems, come back here to ask questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [jQuery REST Client](https://github.com/jpillora/jquery.rest), it's easy to implement

Edit

Add this libraries:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://jpillora.com/jquery.rest/dist/1/jquery.rest.min.js"></script>
```

To resolve `"Vancouver"` and store it in a variable should be:

```
var longName = null;

var client = new $.RestClient('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/');

client.add('geocode', {stripTrailingSlash: true});

client.geocode.read('json', {address: 'Vancouver'}).done(function (data){
  longName = data.results[0].address_components[0].long_name;
});
```